# How to install PYQT in Maya windows?

Tags: python, pyqt, maya

I got this link where installation process of PYQT is given http://download.autodesk.com/us/support/files/maya_documentation/pyqtmaya2016.pdf

but  i can't understand the meaning of Build and install which is given in that link.Can anyone explain me What do you mean by Build and Install given in that link or tell me other possible way to install PYQT in Maya.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

An installer is a compiled executable that downloads / uncompresses certain files and copies them to the appropriate folders in your system, as well as editing any system-specific config files to enable its execution. That way you only need to run the installer, maybe specify some details, and you will be able to use it out-of-the-box.

The 'build' as a number is basically the version of the app, so as to distinguish them either when installing them, debugging or receiving technical assistance. Version and build are not exactly the same, but

Build has another meaning. If you use it as a verb, it means that you will actually be downloading the source code and compiling it for further use. When an app developer actually 'builds' its software and later distributes it, is when he or she assigns a build code, similar to the version, which refers to what I have just explained in the above paragraph.

Usually you can choose amongst downloading an installer and building the code, but if you have less experience, are in a hurry or simply do not want to customise anything from the source code, you would download the installer.

Not all packages have installers. That is why there are package managers that do the job of building the source and copying it to specific directories in your computer.

Comment: thanks for your answer but do i need to copy that code and save code to a file  ?

Comment: @python you were asking about the differences between those two concepts. I don't know what you have to install nor download because I don't know what you have to do, what you need nor how that application works.

Comment: @python With this understanding you should be able to follow the installation process clearly if you know what you are installing. If not, you should actually ask a different question, but not one about the differences between 'build' and 'install'.